# Is it possible to forcefully end a guildleve whose minimum requirements were already fulfilled?

Tags: final-fantasy-14

After joining a Grand Company, you can do guildleves. One particular type I found in Gridania was

> Kill 3 of these monsters under 5 minutes - kill as many as possible.

If you slay 3, you effectively fulfil the minimum requirements for the guildleve. However, the guildleve will not end until those 5 minutes have passed. If you kill more than 3, I think you get a bonus reward.

Is it possible to force the guildleve to end after I have fulfilled the minimum requirements? I'm not interested in the bonuses, and don't want to wait those 5 minutes.

I tried speaking with the guildleves NPC - can't remember what he says but it certainly doesn't end the guildleve. I also opened the quest log, but the options were about the difficulty or abandoning the quest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, there is no way to end the guildleve early.  The whole point of doing them is to gain you experience and gil/company seals (and later for items).  That's exactly what the bonus is.  For those five minutes, you should be killing as many of those creatures as you can.  The experience from killing them isn't great, but what you'll get out of the bonus will make up for that handily, and is one of the more efficient methods of acquiring seals.

If you really don't want to kill more monsters, nothing says you can't just go do something else for the rest of that period.  Once you complete it, you can always get teleported back to the guildleve quest giver.